# What is this email client and how did it get here?

Tags: email, gnome-shell, application, defaults

Earlier today, I was emailing a PDF file, and when I hit the "Email" option in the right-click menu, of all things *Wine* started trying to run. Somehow, a program called "A Wine Application" managed to get set as my default email client. I've remedied this now, but I'm curious how that even happened. Wine is, naturally, a Windows emulator, not an email client. In my GNOME settings, the options for email clients are

- Thunderbird
- Emacs (which *does* have a mail client, even if it's not its primary use)
- A Wine Application

The third option corresponds to `wine-protocol-mailto.desktop`, a file present at `/home/silvio/.local/share/applications` whose contents are

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=A Wine application
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto;
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/silvio/.wine" wine start %u
NoDisplay=true
StartupNotify=true
```

As far as I can tell, that *literally* just starts a Windows CMD terminal running inside Wine, making no attempt to actually, you know, send an email. How on earth did this even get installed as a potential email client, let alone set as the default one? Can anyone explain what happened here?

Comment: Wine itself doesn't do email, yes, but wine applications can, and since those applications can't register themselves as email handlers with Linux DEs, I guess Wine registers itself as the handler for email and then just opens whichever app is registered for email with Wine using Windows mechanisms (and it does this for a bunch of other things as well - there are many posts about Wine becoming the handler for some file format or the other here and elsewhere).